# Difference between screen flags -r and -x

Tags: gnu-screen

What exactly is the difference between `screen -x` and `screen -r`. I know they're both for reattaching to the screen, but not sure I grasp when to use one or the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-r` attaches a detached session, while `-x` attaches an attached session without detaching it, so it runs in both the places at the same time. Another useful option combination is `-d -r` which detaches a session if needed first and then reattaches it.